# Kinect NullReferenceException error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna, kinect

```
void runtime_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    SkeletonFrame skeletonSet = e.SkeletonFrame;

    SkeletonData data = (from s in skeletonSet.Skeletons
                         where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked
                         select s).FirstOrDefault();

    var head = data.Joints[JointID.Head];
    var rightHand = data.Joints[JointID.HandRight];
    var leftHand = data.Joints[JointID.HandLeft];
    SetEllipsePosition(ellipseHead, head, false);
    SetEllipsePosition(ellipseLeftHand, leftHand, isBackGestureActive);
    SetEllipsePosition(ellipseRightHand, rightHand, isForwardGestureActive);

    ProcessForwardBackGesture(head, rightHand, leftHand);
}
```

The line `var head = data.Joints[JointsID.Head];` is giving me an error of type `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: If you use FirstOrDefault, then null value for data is one of the possibilities. You should check for it before accessing Joints

Answer (score 3):

Well `FirstOrDefault()` will return null (assuming `SkeletonData` is a class) if there are no values matching your `where` clause - so I suspect that's the case.

If your code is going to rely on there being at least one result, it would be better to call `First()` rather than `FirstOrDefault`, to avoid hiding the error. I'd personally not bother using a query expression either:

```
SkeletonData data = skeletonSet.Skeletons
               .Where(s => s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
               .First();
```

Or, as pointed out in comments, use the overload of `First` which takes a predicate:

```
SkeletonData data = skeletonSet.Skeletons
               .First(s => s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked);
```

Comment: Don't even need the `.Where` call -- you can just pass the lambda to `.First()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your data variable is probably null.  Set a breakpoint on that line and look at it in the local watches window.